# Is it possible to use grep for the space character

Tags: bash, grep, space

I have a text file (example.txt) like this:

```
100 this is a string
50  word
10
```

(Note that there are trailing space characters on the last line.)

When I do the following in my shell script:

`cat example.txt | sed '1!d' | awk '{for (i=2; i < NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}'` - returns this is a string

`cat example.txt | sed '2!d' | awk '{for (i=2; i < NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}'` - returns word

`cat example.txt | sed '3!d' | awk '{for (i=2; i < NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}'` - returns 10 (incorrect, should be a space character instead)

Is there any method to use grep in bash to return the result I am looking for?

Comment: So what *is* the result you are looking for?  Are you just trying to strip the leading number?  Which space characters on the last line are data to be output, and which are part of the input file format, to be ignored?

Comment: yeap, you can say so, i want to strip the leading number (or any character before the first space character found). the text file must be with the format starting by a number, then a space, and doesn't matter what are the remaining (can be white space too). my goal is to remove the number and the first space, and write the rest into a variable. however, i can't do if the remaining just containing space characters

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to use grep in bash to return the result I am looking for?

Well, `grep` can match space characters.  You have to quote them to avoid the shell interpreting them as delimiters.  But `grep` will output either the whole line or the part of it that matches, depending on the options given to it, and I don't think that will satisfy your output requirement.

It looks like your input format may employ fixed field widths, or at least a fixed-width first field, and that you're trying to remove that first field.  In *that* case, why not use `sed`?  For example,

```
cat example.txt | sed 's/^....//'
```

will remove the first four characters from each line.  You can also spell that

```
sed 's/^....//' example.txt
```

. If you want instead to cut a variable-length head of the line consisting of decimal digits up to the first space then that would be

```
sed 's/^[0-9]* //' example.txt
```

Note that although that's what you said in comments you want, it will produce different output than your `awk` example in the case of your second input line -- it will output a leading space:

```
 word
```

Note also that your `awk`-based approach will replace multiple adjacent whitespace in the retained part of your lines with single spaces.  That behavior could be obtained from `sed`, too, but I'm inclined to think that it's not actually wanted.

Comment: john, thanks for enlighten me in this issue, i already have another workaround for the above situation